# Expand functionality for rows in Richfaces DataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces

I am looking for a way to implement a expand functionality to the rows of a Richfaces DataTable. The user would click a "**+**" link located in the first column (of each row) of the Datatable and the row would "expand" (*meaning new text would be shown between the current row and the next*).

I have that working, the only problem is that all the information in the expanded view is displayed in the first column section of that row. What I am trying to do is to show the "expanded" text in the whole row (as if the "expanded" text row is **not divided by the columns**).

Any suggestions? I'm a bit new at jsf/richfaces, so any *sample code* would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the *breakBefore* attribute on the rich:column component. There is an example of its use on the [RF demo page](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf;jsessionid=BF25011FF0580304AA54312407EF1F65?c=dataTable&tab=usage).

It would work for you if you had the last column define the *breakBefore* attribute. An example:

```
<rich:dataTable id="mytbl" value="#{mybean.mydata}" var="row">
     <rich:column>
        <a4j:commandLink reRender="mytbl">
            <h:graphicImage value="#{row.toggleImage}"></h:graphicImage>
            <a4j:actionparam name="shown" value="#{not row.expand}" assignTo="#{row.expand}"/>
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">col 2</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.col2}"/>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column breakBefore="true">
        spans all the other columns
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way for this is you can use the JQuery feature.

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/BU28E/1/ .

One extra overhead here is you need to check how the rich:dataTable renders as Html and provide the DOM model for jQuery. It is bit tricky to have such feature in richfaces and it needs some complex workarounds.